# C# GoogleDrive API V3 list files, property "parents" always null

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, flysystem-google-drive

I'm trying to find out from files parents value to find out the contents of certain folders. I am using API version three. For some reason, Google does not allow to know the property "parents", always returns null.

What could be the reason? I thought that this is a limited "scopes" parameter, but extending the rights, the result is the same.

***So I connect:***

```
                string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata, DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata};
                var clientId = "id";      // From https://console.developers.google.com
                var clientSecret = "secret";          // From https://console.developers.google.com
                var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret
                },
                scopes,
                Environment.UserName,
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("MyAppsToken111")).Result;

                DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "MyAppName",
                });
```

***So I get files for example:***

```
            var list = service.Files.List().Execute().Files;

            foreach (var file in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file.Parents == null);//always: true == (file.Parents == null)
            }
```

I am sure that at least one file must have a non-null parent property. Can you please tell me what I missed?

[image: SCREEN FILE ITEM FROM LIST]

Comment: add `fields=*` to your URL.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the request like this:

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
listRequest.Fields = "*";
```

After that you can use foreach: `var list = listRequest.Execute().Files;`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want all the fields, for whatever reason, you can just add "**parents**" with in the file fields.

Like so.

```
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType,**parents**)";
```